# Do you use jQuery, extJS, or other javascript libraries with Actionscript and Flex?

Tags: javascript, jquery, apache-flex, actionscript, extjs

Since Actionscript is a proper superset of javascript, it should I suppose be possible. 
Do you use/have you used any of the the javascript extension libraries with Actionscript/Flex/Air?

Comment: But the DOM isn't the same, right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ported some stuff from prototype.js to AS:

http://wiki.alcidesfonseca.com/hacks/prototypeas

Answer (score 3):

The language itself is a proper superset, but the underlying API is not at all the same.  The problems that jQuery and its ilk solve won't be useful for you in ActionScript, so you won't really get much from dropping them into your Flash/Flex project directly.  Most things are already well covered by the default Flash/Flex API, so that probably explain the dearth of add-on libraries.  I would, however, recommend [as3corelib](http://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/z) for processing JSON and handling other data in your ActionScript 3 projects.

Tnanks - I'm already onto as3corelib for JSON.

Answer (score 1):

google around for [as3query](http://ajaxian.com/archives/as3query-jquery-port-to-actionscript)